# Automating Gmail to send mail using java and Selenium WebDriver with added signature text

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I was automating Gmail to send a mail with attachment. The mail contains the in-build signature text of the sender. Every time when I want to type anything in the mail body, the text appears always after the "Regards" and name field. Below is my code.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[text()= 'COMPOSE']")).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//textarea[contains(@aria-label, 'To')]")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//textarea[contains(@aria-label, 'To')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//textarea[contains(@aria-label, 'To')]")).sendKeys("abcd@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.name("subjectbox")).click();
driver.findElement(By.name("subjectbox")).sendKeys("efgh");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[@aria-label='Message Body'])[2]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[@aria-label='Message Body'])[2]")).sendKeys("This is an auto-generated mail");
```

One solution I am using is as below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[@aria-label='Message Body'])[2]")).click();
String s = "Sir,\n This is a auto generated email. \n\n" 
    + driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[@aria-label='Message Body'])[2]")).getText();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[@aria-label='Message Body'])[2]")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[@aria-label='Message Body'])[2]")).sendKeys(s);
```

instead of these two line:
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[@aria-label='Message Body'])[2]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[@aria-label='Message Body'])[2]")).sendKeys("This is an auto-generated mail");

But this solution actually removes all the format of that signature text. Even with signature text, I am not able to get the xpath of the text box using Firebug, I have to delete the complete signature text to get those.
I am a beginner in this automation field. Please help how can I write the text in the mail body before the signature text.

Comment: plz do it like form code you enter signature ,suitable and accurate way

Comment: But why? You can simply send emails via SMTP if you want to do it programatically... This has got to be the most Rube Goldberg solution ever.

Comment: @rajNishKuMar, sorry I am not getting you properly. Actually, manually we can type the text in body by clicking on the text area. The signature appears just below the text. But, using selenium, how can I perform this?

Comment: @max, can I use it through selenium webdriver?

Comment: No - [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) is a protocol used for  example to create desktop email clients - you don't need to automate a web browser at all to send email programically, you just set the content, and headers and off it goes. Automating a browser to use the gmail web is actually the most impractical and convoluted solution ever since it will break if the Gmail team changes the front-end.

Comment: @max thanks. Actually, I am doing this for practice purpose. Ok, I will use SMTP in future if require. But if I will get similar type of problem in any other application, can you please give me any solution that how this problem can be optimized? As, how can I type text just before the signature text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Samiran Banerjee

just use the below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Am.Al.editable.LW-avf>br")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Am.Al.editable.LW-avf")).sendKeys("This is an auto-generated mail");
```

this will type before your signature.

But enter "To" and "subject" and than, wait one or two second.

Comment: Yes, now it is working properly using this .cssSelector(). Thank you.

Comment: Can you please specify what is the reason behind this?

Comment: actually, you just have to get and than click on the right element.

Comment: Little modification, it's working perfectly for me `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Am.Al.editable.LW-avf")).click();`
`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Am.Al.editable.LW-avf")).sendKeys("This is an auto-generated mail");`

Answer (score 1):

Hi plz try like below

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\eclipseProject\\StackOverFlow\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?");
        // gmail login
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("XXXXXXXXXXX.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("XXXXXXXXXX");
        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();

        // some optional actions for reaching gmail inbox
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Google apps']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("gb23")).click();
        // clicks compose
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".T-I.J-J5-Ji.T-I-KE.L3")).click();
        // types message in body without hampering signature
        driver.findElement(By.id(":pg")).sendKeys("This is an auto-generated mail");;

    }
```

Hope this solves your problem look image for better understanding

[image]

also see id in the source code

[image]

Comment: This code is not working for me. It is even not clicking on the message body although I have added the .click() option before .sendkeys(). I am adding my screenshot in answer.

Comment: there is no need to do a click on message body as you  can see i have not used any click on message body thats why its not clicking

Comment: No I have not used the click option initially. But then it was not working at all.

Comment: your xpath is not convincing plz use id for message body and it will work no need to click plz try

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\eclipseProject\\StackOverFlow\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?");
    // gmail login
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("XXXXXXXXXXX.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("XXXXXXXXXX");
    driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();

    // some optional actions for reaching gmail inbox
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Google apps']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("gb23")).click();
    // clicks compose
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".T-I.J-J5-Ji.T-I-KE.L3")).click();
    // types message in body without hampering signature
    driver.findElement(By.id(":pg")).sendKeys("This is an auto-generated mail");;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Gmail_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();    
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    String url = "https://accounts.google.com/signin";
    driver.get(url);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 

    WebElement email_phone = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='identifierId']"));
    email_phone.sendKeys("*******.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext")).click();
    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']"));
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(password));
    System.out.println("\ntest  password");
    password.sendKeys("a*******3");                     
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
    password.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
//    driver.findElement(By.className("ZFr60d")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.className("WaidBe")).click();
    System.out.println("Mail page opened");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.className("z0")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.className("vO")).sendKeys("****************.com");
    driver.findElement(By.className("aoT")).sendKeys("Test email from selenium");
    driver.findElement(By.className("Am")).sendKeys("Hi");
    driver.findElement(By.className("aoO")).click();



    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!